# How do I use same variables between multiple Arduinos?

Tags: variables, arduino, communication

I have multiple Arduinos. I will use one of them as master and it must share variables to other Arduinos. For example, master Arduino will change integer A value, and this integer A value will be changed at other Arduinos as well. How do I connect or communicate those multiple Arduinos? Thanks in advance for any kind of suggestions.

Comment: You cannot directly change variables in other Arduinos. But you can implement a set of commands that the master can send to the slaves and when received the slaves will execute certain code (eg: change variable value)

Comment: Master/slave sounds like I2C, but you can use any communication method.
Keep in mind that it's up to you, to ensure variable A is transmitted to the slave and stored there in the desired target variable, whatever its name is on that node.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and found how to communicate between two Arduinos. First, we will upload codes below then connect our Arduinos as in this image:

[Connection of Arduinos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTZLv.jpg)

If you connect Arduinos before uploading codes, Arduino will give an error. So be sure that you upload your codes before connection. Here is receiver code:

After that, you will receive exact value from sender arduino. You can check it on receiver serial port screen. Hope this helps everyone :)

```
//Receiver Arduino  Code
       String a;
       int yyy;
       void setup() 
       {
       Serial.begin(9600);

        }

        void loop() 
       {
             while(Serial.available()) 
            {
             a = Serial.readString(); //reading value as String
             //yyy=a.toInt(); //this one is for the converting string value to if it is an integer
             Serial.println(a);
             Serial.println(a.length());
             Serial.println(a.charAt(a.length()-1));
            }
        }
```

Here is sender code:

```
   //Sender Arduino code

   void setup() 
   {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   }
   void loop()
   {
   Serial.println("1234i");
   delay(2000);
   }
```